# Windows 10 v1809 ignores “Configure Logon Script Delay” GPO #2

Tags: windows, script, login

Link to:
[Windows 10 v1809 ignores "Configure Logon Script Delay" GPO](https://superuser.com/questions/1427083/windows-10-v1809-ignores-configure-logon-script-delay-gpo/1430497#1430497)

This is my first account and I don't have enough rep points to comment there, apparently. So I have to make a new question...

---

Noticed in my lab (1809) that a logon script seemed very slow to process. At work we're running 1703 and as far as I can tell logon scripts are executed quite fast.

Slow as in about two minutes, not the full five minutes, however.

I tried setting Configure Logon Script Delay to Disabled, however it seemed to make no difference in logon script delay. It kept launching about 2 minutes after desktop was presented.

Answer (score -2):

The solutions below worked for some people. For each suggestion below
I have searched and found user-cases where it solved the problem.
Try them, but as not all similar problems have the same solution,
I cannot guarantee one of them will work for you.

- If this only happens on first login of the day, then the delay is natural.
- If the login is faster without the script, let us know what the script
  does and whether it refers to network shares or websites.
- [Turning off Fast Boot](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)
  may help.
- Try this command:

  ```
  REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "DelayedDesktopSwitchTimeout" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
  ```

  This idea is motivated by this
  [old Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940452/the-welcome-screen-may-be-displayed-for-30-seconds-and-the-logon-scrip).
- From the same article, see in the Group Policy Editor, User Configuration,
  Administrative Templates, System, Scripts, if the value of the policy
  "Run logon scripts synchronously" is different for the slow computer.
- The setting of "Configure Logon Script Delay" may be overridden for that
  computer, and this is something that you may check locally.

Comment: Ideas that **might help** do not make an answer. This answer should be a comment.

Comment: @DavidPostill: How do you want me to put this into a comment? And why isn't a list of possible solutions that worked for some people (I googled each one) make an answer. Not all similar problems have the same solution.

Comment: Well that's up to you to rephrase it. **Might help** sounds like throwing spaghetti at the wall and if it sticks its cooked. Try xyz and it might work or might not work does not make for a good answer ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: "The tongue has the power of life and death". I fixed the offensive text.

Comment: If only you would remember all the lessons I try and teach you ...